# While function - iteratively adding days/months based on variables, accounting for max days of each month

Tags: excel, vba

I would like some help with some VBA code as I am still relatively new. :)

Problem: Creating a VBA function that iteratively adds a number of days or months onto a base date accordingly to a 'periodicity' and 'cutoff' date. Please refer to the picture below.

The original function worked but did not account for days such as the '30th'. For example, if the base date is 30/11/2019 and the cutoff date is 25/08/2020, it will iterate pass Feb 2020 which only has 28 max days. On the Feb iteration, the changedate will become '28/02/2020' and then iterate to '28/03/2020' in March 2020.

Therefore, I would like to save the max base 'changeday' and reimpose it into the final 'changedate'. However, looking at the first row, the adjusted date returns the 1st. The final date should be '30/08/2020'

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Code #ver1:

```
Function getModifiedDate(newdate, cutoff, periodicity)
  While newdate < cutoff
    If periodicity = "Monthly" Then
        newdate = DateAdd("m", 1, newdate)
    ElseIf periodicity = "2-Monthly" Then
        newdate = DateAdd("m", 2, newdate)
    ElseIf periodicity = "Quarterly" Then
        newdate = DateAdd("m", 3, newdate)
    ElseIf periodicity = "6-Monthly" Then
        newdate = DateAdd("m", 6, newdate)
    ElseIf periodicity = "Weekly" Then
        newdate = newdate + 7
    ElseIf periodicity = "Fortnightly" Then
        newdate = newdate + 14

    End If
  Wend
  getModifiedDate = newdate
End Function
```

Code #ver2:

```
Function getModifiedDate(changedate, cutoff, periodicity)
  While changedate < cutoff
    If periodicity = "Monthly" Then
        changeday = Day(changedate)
        changedate = DateAdd("m", 1, changedate)
        lastmonthday = Application.WorksheetFunction.EoMonth(changedate, 0)
            If changeday >= Day(changedate) Then
                changedate = DateSerial(Year(changedate), Month(changedate), changeday)
            End If
    ElseIf periodicity = "2-Monthly" Then
        changeday = Day(changedate)
        changedate = DateAdd("m", 2, changedate)
            If changeday >= Day(changedate) Then
                changedate = DateSerial(Year(changedate), Month(changedate), changeday)
            End If
    ElseIf periodicity = "Quarterly" Then
        changeday = Day(changedate)
        changedate = DateAdd("m", 3, changedate)
            If changeday >= Day(changedate) Then
                    changedate = DateSerial(Year(changedate), Month(changedate), changeday)
                End If
    ElseIf periodicity = "6-Monthly" Then
        changeday = Day(changedate)
        changedate = DateAdd("m", 6, changedate)
            If changeday >= Day(changedate) Then
                changedate = DateSerial(Year(changedate), Month(changedate), changeday)
            End If
    ElseIf periodicity = "Weekly" Then
        changedate = changedate + 7
    ElseIf periodicity = "Fortnightly" Then
        changedate = changedate + 14

    End If
  Wend
  getModifiedDate = changedate
End Function
```

[image: Excel screenshot example:]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest a different algorithm where, instead of adding the periods one at a time, you add the appropriate number of periods **all at once**.  That way you avoid the issue of intervening months not having the requisite number of days.

You can do this by calculating the "period difference" between `changedate` and `cutoff`, and then checking to be sure your result is not less than `cutoff`.

You should also add a check and a result in case the Periodicity is not one of the designated types.  Probably with a `Case Else` statement.

For example:

```
Option Explicit
Function getModifiedDate(changedate As Date, cutoff As Date, periodicity As String) As Date
    Dim L As Long
    Dim dtTemp As Long

'Sanity check
If changedate > cutoff Then
    getModifiedDate = changedate 'or cutoff, depending on what you want
    Exit Function
End If

Select Case periodicity
    Case "Monthly"
        L = DateDiff("m", changedate, cutoff)
        dtTemp = DateAdd("m", L, changedate)
        getModifiedDate = DateAdd("m", L + IIf(dtTemp < cutoff, 1, 0), changedate)
    Case "2-Monthly"
        L = DateDiff("m", changedate, cutoff) \ 2
        dtTemp = DateAdd("m", L * 2, changedate)
        getModifiedDate = DateAdd("m", L * 2 + IIf(dtTemp < cutoff, 2, 0), changedate)
    Case "6-Monthly"
        L = DateDiff("m", changedate, cutoff) \ 6
        dtTemp = DateAdd("m", L * 6, changedate)
        getModifiedDate = DateAdd("m", L * 6 + IIf(dtTemp < cutoff, 6, 0), changedate)
    Case "Quarterly"
        L = DateDiff("q", changedate, cutoff)
        dtTemp = DateAdd("q", L, changedate)
        getModifiedDate = DateAdd("q", L + IIf(dtTemp < cutoff, 1, 0), changedate)
    Case "Weekly"
        L = DateDiff("ww", changedate, cutoff)
        dtTemp = DateAdd("ww", L, changedate)
        getModifiedDate = DateAdd("ww", L + IIf(dtTemp < cutoff, 1, 0), changedate)
    Case "Fortnightly"
        L = DateDiff("ww", changedate, cutoff) \ 2
        dtTemp = DateAdd("ww", L * 2, changedate)
        getModifiedDate = DateAdd("ww", L * 2 + IIf(dtTemp < cutoff, 2, 0), changedate)
End Select

End Function
```

[image]